# determine $n_0 $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Q:for $\varepsilon\gt 0$,determine an $n_0$ such that

$|$($\frac{3+4n}{2n+1}$)$^3$$-8|$$\lt\varepsilon $ for $n\ge n_0$.?

Sol :

I use  this theorem 
If $x_n\to 2$ and$ f (x)= x^3$ is cont. at 2 then $f (x_n)\to f (2)$
Note: $x_n =\frac{3+4n}{2n+1}$

f (x) cont. at 2 then

for given any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ , there exist $\delta \gt 0$ such that

$|x^3-8|\lt \varepsilon $ , $|x-2|\lt \delta $ 
$|x-2||x^2+2x+4|\lt \varepsilon  $

find upper bound for $|x^2+2x+4|$
 We have : 
 $|x-2|\lt \delta $ , choose $\delta $ = 1

$-1 \lt x-2 \lt 1$ ,

$1 \lt x \lt 3$
,
 $1 \lt x^2 \lt 9$,

$2\lt 2x \lt 6$

$7 \lt x^2+2x+4 \lt 19$

So 
$|x-2|\lt \frac {\varepsilon}{19} $ 
Choose $\delta = \frac {\varepsilon}{19} $

We have also $x_n\to 2$:

for given any $\delta$, there exist $n_0$ 
Such that :

$| \frac{3+4n}{2n+1}-2|$$ \lt \delta$, $n \ge n_0$ .

then
$\frac{1}{2n+1} \lt \frac{1}{2n} \lt \delta$,
so
$n \gt \frac{1}{2\delta}$

Choose $n_0 \ge \frac{1}{2\delta}$
and 
$\delta = \frac {\varepsilon}{19}$
   so $n_0 \ge \frac{19}{2\varepsilon }$

Is it true?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any theorem. Just handle the given inequality properly. The target inequality which needs to be satisfied is $$\left|\frac{(3+4n)^{3}}{(2n+1)^{3} }-8\right|<\varepsilon$$ which is the same as $$\left|\frac{48n^2+60n+19} {(2n+1)^{3}}\right|<\varepsilon $$ Since $n$ is a positive integer the modulus signs in above inequality are redundant and thus our goal is to satisfy the following inequality $$\frac{48n^2+60n+19}{8n^3+12n^{2}+6n+1}<\varepsilon \tag{1}$$ Next we note the obvious inequality $$\frac{48n^2+60n+19}{8n^3+12n^{2}+6n+1}<\frac{48n^2+72n+36}{8n^3+12n^2+6n}=\frac{6}{n}$$ From the above inequality it is clear that if we have $6/n<\varepsilon $ then the inequality $(1)$ is automatically satisfied. And therefore if we take $n_{0}=\lfloor 6/\varepsilon \rfloor +1$ then for $n\geq n_{0}$ we have $6/n<6/n_{0}<\varepsilon$ and hence our goal $(1)$ is achieved whenever $n\geq n_{0}=\lfloor 6/\varepsilon\rfloor +1$.

Comment: but is it true when use the theorem as another solution

Comment: @user508518: your solution is almost correct and requires a minor fix. The number $\delta$ should be equal to $\min(1,\varepsilon/19)$. But more importantly it is unnecessarily complicated.